# Запретить выход объекта за границы камеры

Tags: unity3d

Как запретить выход объекта за пределы камеры в 3d игре, мне нужно чтобы нельзя было выйти объекту за пределы камеры во всех четырёх сторонах(камера стоит сверху типа как в 2D игре)

Вот этот скрипт прекреплён к объекту которые не должен выходить за края камеры:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class PlayerBehaviour : MonoBehaviour
{
    void Start()
    {
    }

    void Update()
    {
          AntiExitPos();
    }

    void AntiExitPos()
    {
          Vector3 cameraToObject = transform.position - Camera.main.transform.position;
          // отрицание потому что игровые объекты в данном случае находятся ниже камеры по оси y
          float distance = -Vector3.Project(cameraToObject, Camera.main.transform.forward).y;

           // вершины "среза" пирамиды видимости камеры на необходимом расстоянии от камеры
           Vector3 leftBot  = Camera.main.ViewportToWorldPoint(new Vector3(0, 0, distance));
           Vector3 rightTop = Camera.main.ViewportToWorldPoint(new Vector3(1, 1, distance));

           // границы в плоскости XZ, т.к. камера стоит выше остальных объектов
           float x_left  = leftBot.x;
           float x_right = rightTop.x;
           float z_top   = rightTop.z;
           float z_bot   = leftBot.z;

           // ограничиваем объект в плоскости XZ
           Vector3 clampedPos = transform.position;
           clampedPos.x = Mathf.Clamp(clampedPos.x, x_left, x_right);
           clampedPos.z = Mathf.Clamp(clampedPos.z, z_bot, z_top);
           transform.position = clampedPos;
      }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Казалось бы, простейший вопрос на тему viewport`а камеры...

Значения координат на обеих осях внутри viewport'а камеры принимают значения от 0 до 1. Если точка принимает другие значения - она лежит **вне** viewport`а данной камеры.

Поскольку объект не должен выходить за пределы видимости камеры, значит и его координаты в проекции на viewport камеры должны быть в пределах `[0, 1]`.

Добиться такого можно 2 способами:

1. `object world pos 
   -> object viewport pos 
   -> clamp object viewport pos to [0..1] 
   -> object world pos`

В таком случае переводы из world pos в `[0..1]` viewport`а приводит к огромным потерям точности и на выходе получаем чушь, проверено опытным путем, - не подходит.

2. Получить прямоугольное сечение пирамиды видимости камеры в мировых координатах, и проверять координаты других объектов относительно этого прямоугольника - работает отлично. Об этом способе и пойдет дальше речь.

---

В данном случае речь пойдет об ограничении позиции одного объекта, но переписать это для использования на массиве объектов не составит никакого труда.

Для начала найдем тот самый "срез" фрустума камеры - обычный прямоугольник. Как я уже написал выше, viewport всегда ограничен, конкретные координаты зависят от движка. В случае Unity - это `[0..1]`. Ну вот и находим координаты углов viewport'а в мировых координатах, используя координаты его краев в системы координат самого viewport'а. Хоть viewport и является прямоугольником, мы передаем туда 3 координату - расстояние от камеры до интересующего нас объекта, тут вроде все логично, так что не буду разжевывать.

```
Camera cam = Camera.main;

Vector3 cameraToObject = transform.position - cam.transform.position;
float distance = -Vector3.Project(cameraToObject, Camera.main.transform.forward).y;

Vector3 leftTop  = cam.ViewportToWorldPoint(new Vector3(0, 1, distance));
Vector3 leftBot  = cam.ViewportToWorldPoint(new Vector3(0, 0, distance));
Vector3 rightBot = cam.ViewportToWorldPoint(new Vector3(1, 0, distance));
Vector3 rightTop = cam.ViewportToWorldPoint(new Vector3(1, 1, distance));
```

Если закинем все это дело в gizmos - получим следующую картину:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На самом деле прямоугольник можно определить ровно 2 диагонально противоположными точками - этого вполне хватит, чтобы получить ограничения по обеим координатам.

Итоговый код:

```
Vector3 cameraToObject = transform.position - Camera.main.transform.position;
// отрицание потому что игровые объекты в данном случае находятся ниже камеры по оси y
float distance = -Vector3.Project(cameraToObject, Camera.main.transform.forward).y;

// вершины "среза" пирамиды видимости камеры на необходимом расстоянии от камеры
Vector3 leftBot  = Camera.main.ViewportToWorldPoint(new Vector3(0, 0, distance));
Vector3 rightTop = Camera.main.ViewportToWorldPoint(new Vector3(1, 1, distance));

// границы в плоскости XZ, т.к. камера стоит выше остальных объектов
float x_left  = leftBot.x;
float x_right = rightTop.x;
float z_top   = rightTop.z;
float z_bot   = leftBot.z;

// ограничиваем объект в плоскости XZ
Vector3 clampedPos = transform.position;
clampedPos.x = Mathf.Clamp(clampedPos.x, x_left, x_right);
clampedPos.z = Mathf.Clamp(clampedPos.z, z_bot, z_top);
transform.position = clampedPos;
```

---

Результат работы:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

P.S.

Понятное дело, что этот подход можно оптимизировать и, к примеру, получать координаты viewport'а ровно 1 раз, если высота камеры и глубины всех элементов в игре постоянная и одинаковая. Зависят такие оптимизации уже от конкретного случая.

Comment: @M.Green, я изначально вообще хотел просто клампить положение объекта в координатах viewport'а и потом эти же координаты переносить обратно в мировые координаты, но точность float'а подводит.

Comment: У меня объект мерцает справа и слева, что делать?

Comment: Вот gif: https://imgur.com/a/FCCKbet

Comment: @AimonZ. Прикрепите полный код в вопрос, мой код не должен вызывать такое поведение.

Comment: Всё я прикрепил полный код к теме.

Comment: @RiotBr3aker, А можно ваш тестовый проект с этим кодом?

Comment: @AimonZ., он ничем не отличается от вашего, как у меня появится время - я проведу побольше тестов.

Comment: @AimonZ., провел несколько тестов - ничего не ломается и работает так, как и задумано. Можете прикрепить скриншот настроек камеры?

Comment: Вот я снял видео с экрана там я создал проект с нуля и вставляю ваш код также там можно увидеть настройки камеры: https://streamable.com/qb80g. Может быть я делаю что-то не так?

Comment: @AimonZ., вы для чего-то повернули камеру на 90 градусов относительно оси y, что и поломало системы координат, для чего вам это нужно? Если это не не обходимое действие - просто не вращайте камеру. В противном случае нужно подумать.

Comment: Чтобы камера была сверху и смотрела вниз а не в бок

Comment: @AimonZ., для этого камеру нужно вращать на 90 градусов относительно оси **x**, причем здесь вращение относительно оси **y**?

Comment: Получается я здесь виноват. Простите за потраченное  ваше время.

Comment: @AimonZ., да ладно, с кем не бывает, главное, что решили проблему. Если данный ответ вам помог и решил поставленный вопрос - отметьте его верным, чтобы другие его видели.

Comment: @RiotBr3aker, А можно сделать чтобы объекты не заходил на половину за камеру а упирался сразу в край?

Comment: @AimonZ., можно, но это уже другой вопрос, не вижу смысла расписывать его здесь или тем более в комментариях.

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант можно рассмотреть использование [OnBecameInvisible](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnBecameInvisible.html), но правда метод будет срабатывать когда объект выйдет за пределы видимости камеры и тогда можно сменить направление движения объекта чтобы вернуть его обратно. Обратите внимание, что компонент с методом [OnBecameInvisible](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnBecameInvisible.html) должен находиться на объекте с компонентом Renderer.

Можно сделать костыльное решение: разместить со всех четырех сторон объекта по одному прозрачному Quad с навешанным скриптом, который будет как триггер срабатывать и отправлять объект в обратную сторону.

Comment: Чем вариант с quad`ами отличается от коллайдеров, предложенных ранее?

Comment: @RiotBr3aker так Quad вкладываем вложенными объектами в тот объект который не должен выходить  и не надо ничего выравнивать и позиционировать в зависимости от размеров экрана. Кодинга минимум, надо только прописать как себя вести если выходишь за пределы камеры

Comment: @RiotBr3aker Quad будет работать как тригер для самого объекта, что дальше нельзя двигаться. Настраивая позицию quad регулируем границу до края экрана и делаем все визуально без gizmo и рассчетов.  Тем более такая штука будет работать при разворотах камеры, при изменении ее размеров, изменении FOV и бог знает чего еще влияющего на размер картинки). Все проблемы по отслеживанию за зоной видимости на себя заберет движок.

Comment: "Нет расчетов"? А "отправлять объект в обратную сторону" сам собой будет работать? Причем здесь вообще gizmos? Я его использовал, чтобы показать границы объекта. `OnBecameInvisible` в принципе не подходит для этой задачи - объект сначала исчезнет и только потом вы что-то с ним сделаете. Про решение через Quad'ы я вообще молчу, те же коллайдеры, только вместо обычных коллайдеров будет 4 MonoBehaviour`а, что вообще абсурд.

Comment: @RiotBr3aker, уважаемый, я не говорю что этот способ идеален. Подход предложенный вами для определения позиции исходя из ViewPort правильнее, правда тоже есть свои сложности с определением области удаления объекта от края если у него сложная форма и размер. В предложенном мной варианте если объект не крутится относительно камеры выставление триггеров дает наглядную возможность определить до какой степени можно приближаться к краю экрана (или входить в него). Ну а поведение по возврату в область камеры писать придется при любом раскладе, здесь логика определяется задачей.

Comment: Что сложного 1 раз через `bounds` рендерера узнать размер объекта? Точно так же определяет, до какой степени можно приближаться к краю. На этом сайте, вроде как, приветствуется критика, разве нет? Вы просто переписали чужой ответ, поменяв шило на мыло, вот я и написал, что это плохо и лучше так не делать.

Comment: @RiotBr3aker. Одно да потому. Я не против критики. Просто еще один вариант решения. От коллайдеров отличается тем что нет нужды использовать физику для решения задачи. Каждый имеет право на свое мнение, я ваше выслушал, уважайте и мое. Давите так, как будто у задачи может быть только одно решение, будьте гибче.

Answer (score 0):

Эм... Поставить коллайдеры в тех местах, где находится граница камеры.

Comment: Т.е. подключать физику ради одной фичи? Такое себе решение)

Comment: Не совсем пойдёт. Камера-то зависит от разрешения экрана, а значит, что при запуске на другом разрешении граница поставленная с помощью коллайдеров останется совсем в другом месте

Comment: @M.Green что мешает двигать эти коллайдеры в зависимости от разрешения?

Comment: @RiotBr3aker, то, что раз мы и так можем узнать "границы", то какой смысл вообще ставить там ещё и коллайдеры?

Comment: @M.Green а ставить коллайдер на "землю" - сильно лучше? :)

Comment: @RiotBr3aker, сильно :) как минимум тем, что поставив коллайдер на землю можно рассчитать видимые границы этой "земли". Вариант без коллайдера на земле я тоже предложил, правда, он не учитывает наклона плоскости - автору придётся додумывать. Вариант с "границами" требует чтобы игрок с ними сталкивался, а вариант с "землёй" позволяет использовать её коллайдер только для одиночного расчёта на старте. При этом, если слою земли выключить столкновение с другими слоями внутри физики, то обрабатываться этот коллайдер вообще не будет нигде кроме рукотворного "луча" для поиска границ.

Comment: @M.Green, а я где-то сказал, что решение с коллайдерами в виде границ лучше вашего? Они оба костыльные. Что если в игре вообще не используется физика? Зато ради рейкастинга давайте подключим еще один поток, почему бы и нет. "границы" ограниченной плоскости можно найти через viewport, который в разы дешевле и вообще не требует никакой физики, да и к тому же позволяет работать с объектами, имеющими разную глубину z, чем ваше "решение" похвастаться не может.

Comment: @RiotBr3aker, Вы задали вопрос "сильно лучше ли" один вариант другого - я ответил "да" и пояснил почему. Где я сказал, что это решение самое лучшее? Чтобы помочь человеку, я дал развёрнутый ответ относительно известного мне способа. Вам известен лучший способ? Так поделитесь им - я с удовольствием улучшу свой скил и буду только рад, что автор вопроса получит более качественный ответ. Мне совсем непонятна суть нашего диалога. Банальное "этот способ плох вот этим, можно сделать "вот так", приду домой оставлю развёрнутый ответ" и никаких вопросов больше не останется.

Comment: @M.Green ну а я вам ответил, что ваш способ не сильно лучше, проблемы ровным счетом никакой. Я объяснил, почему ваш способ плохо, вот и все. Думаю, это лучше, чем молча поставить минус, не так ли?

Comment: @RiotBr3aker, разворачивали бы тогда дискуссию под моим ответом) так всё же, что там нужно делать с вьюпортами?

Comment: @M.Green, оформил ответ.

Comment: @RiotBr3aker мы в своем проекте использовали подход с коллайдерами, у нас было несколько столов соединенных вместе и требовалось чтобы окна не вылетали за пределы обзора. Коллайдеры работали как триггеры и расставить их по краям экранов было простым и наглядным решением. Через расчеты `vieport` тоже можно было бы, но отлаживаться по UI с сетевыми окнами стало бы на порядок сложнее. Это я к тому что выбор решения в первую очередь зависит от поставленной задачи.

Answer (score 0):

Возможно это вам поможет

```
    Vector3 screenPoint = Camera.main.WorldToViewportPoint("позиция вашего объекта");
    bool onScreen = screenPoint.z > 0 && screenPoint.x > 0 && screenPoint.x < 1 && screenPoint.y > 0 && screenPoint.y < 1;
```